# Visibility Issue of eCharts Graphs in Google AdSense Preview Impacting Ad Approval on Next.js Project

Tags: reactjs, next.js, adsense, echarts

I am developing a project using Next.js and have integrated the eCharts library for data visualization. I've encountered an issue that might be impacting my Google AdSense account approval. During the AdSense configuration previews, the eCharts graphs are not visible.

My website recently faced issues in getting approval for ads from Google AdSense. The reasons cited were:

- Lack of content or content of little value.
- Website still being created or edited.
- Website being used for alerts, navigation, or other behavioral purposes.

I am concerned that during the AdSense review process, the invisibility of eCharts graphs in the preview might lead reviewers to mistakenly believe that my website lacks content or is incomplete, potentially impacting my approval.

I seek clarity on the following:

1. Is it normal for eCharts graphs to be invisible in the Google AdSense preview?
2. Will this issue affect the visibility of graphs on the live website, and could it be misinterpreted by AdSense reviewers?
3. Is there a known compatibility issue between the Google AdSense script and eCharts?

Understanding the nature of this problem is crucial for me, as it could significantly impact my website's functionality and monetization capability. Any insights or similar experiences shared would be highly valuable.

Thank you!

Comment: I dont know anything about google AdSense but let me tackle this from another angle. Are the echarts graphs usally visable? How do you verify that?

Comment: Thank you for your response! Yes, the eCharts graphs are indeed integrated into my pages and are visibly rendered when viewed directly on the website. While I'm not entirely sure how to verify their visibility in technical terms for Google AdSense's preview mechanism, they are certainly accessible and functional for site visitors. If there are specific details or technical insights you believe might help address the visibility issue within AdSense previews, I would greatly appreciate your guidance. Let me know if you need more information from my side.

Thanks again for your help! :)

Comment: Maybe it has to do with echarts charts beeing an empty div before initialization and [server-side rendering](https://echarts.apache.org/en/tutorial.html#Server-side%20Rendering) could be helpful? But this is just a complete guess, otherwise I have no ideas.